# How to translate a Java Enumeration to C#?

Tags: c#, java, enumeration

I have some Java code and I would like to translate it to C#.
srcParams is a Hashtable.

This is the Java code:

```
for (Enumeration keys = srcParams.keys(); keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    key = keys.nextElement();
    destParams.Add(key, srcParams[key]);
}
```

And this is my attempt in C#

```
IEnumerator key = srcParams.Keys.GetEnumerator();
while (key.MoveNext()) {
    destParams.Add(key, srcParams[key]);
}
```

Could you tell me if it's correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(var key in srcParams.Keys) {
    destParams.Add(key, srcParams[key]);
}
```

What you have is close to being okay, just rename the variables and add the use of `IEnumerator.Current`:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = srcParams.Keys.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    object key = enumerator.Current;
    destParams.Add(key, srcParams[key]);
}
```